# Shooting down or capturing AI transporters

Tags: x3-reunion

Is there any way to capture AI transporters (like Argon/Boron Food/Weapons/etc Transporters) roaming through the sectors ?

When I shoot them down to near destruction and communicate with them to surrender their ships, they reply with something like "OK don't shoot, just take the ship" but nothing happens.

Also when I completely destroy them, there is absolutely nothing left in the debris. For instance, before attacking them I scan their cargo and there was a humongous amount of Food, but not a single one floating in space afterwards.

Is there any way to effectively looting/plundering/capturing them, or are they completely decorative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These freighters will behave like other non-capital craft - there is a chance the pilot will eject after the craft is damaged enough, and a chance for some carge to be left floating about if the craft is destroyed. You cannot coerce them to eject by contacting them.

Comment: Finally I've managed to capture one out of 9, alas almost %90 percent of the goods were damaged in the fight.
So it seems their surrender rate is very low comparing to the pirates. 
Thank you for your help.